# Need to add cognalys sdk to android app

Tags: android

I am making an android app which needs phone number verification.

I want to use "Cognalys SDK" in my application.

Please help me to understand how to add it in my application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cognalys` library for android phone no verification. Integrating it in android you need to add SDK into the library here is the sample code for it [Link](https://github.com/cognalys/Cogdemov2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample app and library available in [Github](https://github.com/cognalys/Cogdemov2) . Check it out. You can add the code in sample app into your app and implement your required functionality